# VF Value Element in an List/Array

Tags: apex, visualforce

If I have *multiple input fields* on my page, can I assign their value to elements in a *list/array*?? Is this even possible and I don't understand the syntax?

**Example:**

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="pageController">
  <apex:selectList value="{!array[0]}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!optionsList}" />
  </apex:selectList>
  <apex:selectList value="{!array[1]}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!optionsList}" />
      </apex:selectList>
  <apex:selectList value="{!array[2]}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!optionsList}" />
      </apex:selectList>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class pageController {
   public List<String> array {get; set;} // array of input values on page submit
   public List<SelectOption> optionsList {get; set;} // assigned in controller
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that does seem possible. Except that the array needs to be initialized with some values in it. (And array is a reserved word).

With a few tweaks, what you've pasted above worked. When I clicked the commandButton, it correctly bound the selected values in each list to the elements in the list and displayed this on the vf page. Very handy I think !

```
<apex:page controller="pageController">
<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:commandButton value="Test" action="{!test}" rerender="out" status="status"/>
  <apex:selectList value="{!arrayValue[0]}" size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!optionsList}" />
  </apex:selectList>
  <apex:selectList value="{!arrayValue[1]}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!optionsList}" />
      </apex:selectList>
  <apex:selectList value="{!arrayValue[2]}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!optionsList}" />
      </apex:selectList>

      <apex:outputPanel id="out">
        <apex:actionstatus id="status" startText="testing...">
            <apex:facet name="stop">
                <apex:outputPanel>
                    <p>You have selected:</p>
                    <apex:dataList value="{!arrayValue}" var="c">{!c}</apex:dataList>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionstatus>
    </apex:outputPanel>

      </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class (Controller):

```
public class pageController {
   public List<String> arrayValue {get; set;} // array of input values on page submit
   public List<SelectOption> optionsList {get; set;} // assigned in controller

   public pageController(){
       optionsList = new List<SelectOption>{};
       arrayValue = new List<String>{'','',''}; //INITIALISE LIST
       optionsList.add(new SelectOption('Hello', 'Hello'));
       optionsList.add(new SelectOption('World', 'World'));
       optionsList.add(new SelectOption('Java', 'Java'));
   }

   public PageReference test(){
       return null;
   }

   }
```

Comment: Awesome thanks @techtrekker your right about the keyword and the default values ... I can fix that -- just wanted to get the question up.

Comment: Quite enjoyed that ! Learnt something new too. Cheers Jordan !

Comment: Just for completeness I'm pretty sure you could use an apex:repeat here too.

Comment: You mean selectList within repeat ? Doesn't seem to work - just tried it. Doesn't recognise the var to be able to bind to the value attribute of the selectList